# Saving large images to MVC Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, image-uploading

I'm building an android and iOS app that let's the user save multiple images at the same time.

When either app saves a few images at a time ( 1-3images), i can see the image object come througg the api and succesfully save.

When I stress test the save to over 10 images the api, the api still gets the request but the image object is NULL.

This behaviour happens on both iOS  (using Alamofire) and android  (using Volley ) so I don't believe its the apps.

Any ideas on what could cause this?

The image object is made up of

```
int    Id
byte[] ImageFile
string ImageName
```

Comment: I might suggest making a MIME multi-part message which contains multiple images at once. Or modify your client to only send 1 image upload at a time.

Comment: Saving images individually is my last option. I am currently saving a parent object which includes the images. This then saves the images with the parent object primary key.